# Third party API off-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I recently stumbled across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545986/facebook-ip-to-get-wall-post-and-show-it-on-my-website) although poorly written as well as lack of detail, is borderline on-topic, though from a response given by **an 80K user** I am unsure whether it is on-topic anymore

> Yes, and the vendor of the API - if intended to be used with PHP - should have given that to you. If there is a problem with the materials provided by the vendor, contact the vendor. We can not offer support for third-party code, however we do answer programming questions about code you've a) written yourself or b) you've showed that you understand it (e.g. code by someone else but you are using it as a programmer) and you are asking about a programming problem (no support requests please for third-party API usage).

I am most likely horrible at searching for I cannot find where in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic or here at Meta that API usage is off-topic. Can someone assist in resolving my uncertainty? Specifically

> (no support requests please for third-party API usage)

Comment: Well, he does make a point about "support requests" - those are things only the support dept can answer. Except I can't even tell if this is a support request. It doesn't seem to be at first blush.

Comment: One of the reasons I *ignored* all FB tags ...

Comment: It's very easy to say "read the manual" or Stack Overflow doesn't do "code requests", even the close options have it "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist". The current comments as is, are a very long winded way to say it in my opinion.

Comment: @HamZa and your need to comment about a question related to Facebook means...

Comment: We're talking about "support requests", not "code requests" here. (Or at least, I am anyway.)

Comment: from a brief look, that question does not seem to be very programming-related

Comment: Define a support request, because at this point it sounds very ambiguous.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure what you are saying, the question is poorly written, poorly defined, shows minimal understanding of the code, but in no such way is it **not** programming-related.

Comment: OP wrote he needs PHP code for that. Asking for code inherently is programming related, however not that kind of programming related question we like to support, don't we?

Comment: OP doesn't seem to demonstrate a minimal understanding... not sure if it's a support request though.

Answer (score 5):

Programming/Support

My understanding of programming is that the person who asks the question *is* programming. The best example is the own code you write from scratch.

Programming does not compute alway good to what others did. E.g. programming that was done and is now shielded from you behind a webservice API or third-party code that you have managed to download but that you don't understood or haven't even looked at.

I tend to put those programming related questions (as the OP normally interacts with those third party code or APIs) into the support domain, the OP needs support in using those interfaces.

For example the question "How do I post an Image to my Twitter account" is a perfectly valid programming question as long as it's about posting that image via the API.

However it is firsthand a support request for me which should be directed off-site because the OP has not provided anything specific we can influence (as programmers) if we were confronted with the same question.

It's similar like with asking for off-site resources, tutorials etc..

I hope this makes it a little bit more clear what's behind when I try to explain the OP in which part the question does benefit from an improvement. I also offer help with common problems, but it still doesn't feel well to be on-topic.